# Quota on MooseFS, Samba shares under AD

Tags: samba, shared-folders, quota, dfs

I have a windows domain controller and 4 linux servers attached to it as a storage. On linux servers I have centrifydc-samba  to share user folders, and the same folders are mfs chunkservers that mount their moosefs exports. I need to limit each user so user can see how free space he/she has in the windows machine.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In MooseFS you can set up "project" quotas (e.g. homedir or sth).

`man mfssetquota`:

> Quota is set on a directory. It can be set in one of 4 ways: for
>   number of inodes inside the directory (total sum of the subtree's
>   inodes) with -i, -I options, for sum of (logical)
>          file  lengths with -l, -L options, for sum of chunk sizes (not considering goals) with -s, -S options and for physical hdd space
>   (more or less chunk sizes multiplied by goal of each chunk) with -r,
>   -R options.  Small letters set soft quota, capital letters set hard quota.
>          -a and -A options in mfsdelquota mean all kinds of quota. Quota behaviour is described below.  For soft quota grace period can be
>   defined using -p option. When grace period is not given then default
>   value will be used (option defined in mfsmaster.cfg or seven days if
>   it's
>          not defined there).

The best solution for you is to set a "total size hard quota", which does not take goal under consideration.

The command to set it is as follows (e.g.):

```
mfssetquota -S 10TiB /mnt/mfs/user1
```

Next, to report the quota properly to samba, you have to mount a share with `-S` (equivalent to `-o mfssubfolder`) parameter:

`man mfsmount`:

> ```
>    -S PATH, -o mfssubfolder=PATH
>          mount specified MooseFS directory (default is /, i.e. whole filesystem)
> ```

```
mfsmount -o mfssubfoler=user1 /mnt/homedirs/user1
```

and then share it through Samba. The thing is, that you have to mount and share through Samba each directory separately to enable properly reporting free space etc.